# How can I run Java page with Wordpress?

Tags: java, wordpress, templates

The client wants to move his current website from Movable Type to Wordpress. The problem I'm seeing is he's running a couple of Java pages and his idea is to modify the `.jsp` files and implement them inside a new Wordpress template. Is this even possible? What would be the best approach for implementing Java code in Wordpress?

Comment: Translate the java code into php

Comment: Analyze what the pages do and rewrite them in Wordpress.  You are seriously not considering integrating Movable Type into Wordpress, say this is not possible.

Comment: How come there are .jsp pages in Movable Type? Smells like technical debt? Did the website run on a Tomcat server before the client decided Movable Type was better?

Comment: @toongeorges , I've already moved all the content from Movable to WP, it was a pain with fixing the formatting of the export file and there was around 4500 posts in total. The .jsp pages were made custom on Movable, just like you would add a custom PHP file in WP and call it via URL. I'm not entirely sure about the server specs and how they did it, my main problem is getting those .jsp pages run on PHP. Which is not possible. I guess it will need to be translated from Java to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily keep both Movable Type and Wordpress with links to one another's pages, but if the goal is to get rid of Movable Type altogether, You'll have to translate the Java code into PHP.